# Deriving from a class template with + operator overloading

Tags: templates, c++11

I'm trying everything but unsuccessfully i can't get it work :/

For example i have these classes:

```
class Thing
{
public:
    Thing() = default;

    int getId() { return m_id; }

private:
    int m_id;
};

template<class ThingType>
class Base
{
public:
    Base(const std::vector<ThingType>& things)
        : m_things(things) {};

    Base<ThingType> operator+(Base<ThingType>& rhs)
    {
       // if not duplicated by id add new things
    }

protected:
    std::vector<ThingType> m_things;
};

class FooThings : public Base<Thing>
{
public:
    FooThings(const std::vector<Thing>& things)
        : Base(things) {};
};
```

I want to use it like

```
FooThings foo1(...);
FooThings foo2(...);
FooThings foos = foo1 - foo2;
```

but it gives me error "'initializing': cannot convert from 'Base' to 'FooThings'". I know that im doing something wrong in construction of my operator overloading code but I dunno what or how to write it properly

Comment: You will need another `operator+` overload for class `FooThings`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CRTP:

```
template<class ThingType, class Derived>
class Base
{
public:
    Base(const std::vector<ThingType>& things)
        : m_things(things) {};

    Derived operator+(const Base<ThingType, Derived>& rhs)
    {
        std::vector<ThingType> sum = m_things;
        sum.insert(end(sum), begin(rhs.m_things), end(rhs.m_things));
        return Derived(sum);
    }

protected:
    std::vector<ThingType> m_things;
};
```

I modified your base class introducing another template parameter, `Derived` that I use to implement `operator+`

Comment: This is a good solution of my problem. I didn't know that is possible to do that kind of trick. Thank you very much ! :)